# when to copy Resource database and when system databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, configuration, migration

> "The Resource database is a read-only database that contains all the system objects that are included with SQL Server" [1]

This sounds that one database from one instance (which one?) contains all information on the whole SQL Server, though I observe that each instance has its own Resource database copy.
Is this phrase "with SQL Server" incorrect and should be read as "with instance of SQL Server"?

"In earlier versions of SQL Server, upgrading required dropping and creating system objects. Because the Resource database file contains all system objects, an upgrade is now accomplished simply by copying the single Resource database file to the local server" [1]

**Exactly which system objects were dropped** when upgrading from SQL Server 2000 to 2005? Please give me a link describing it.

Where is the procedure describing simple copying of one Resource database (and which one?) in upgrading from SQL Server 2005 to 2008, or from 2008 to 2008 R2?  Please give me a link.

How is the procedure *Moving System Databases*[2] to be understood?

[1]
Resource Database (SQL Server 2008 R2 Books Online)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190940.aspx

[2]
Moving System Databases (SQL Server 2008 R2 Books Online)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't copy the resource database: it's an installable by service packs and hotfixes etc. It's not an actual database in the same concept as master or "MyDB". This is why you don't see it in SSMS.

Don't get hung up on it: it's of no relevance day to day. Really. Unless you are [moving master](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345408%28SQL.90%29.aspx) which should be quite rare of course, especially if you have "standard" build. This is straightforward: if you don't understand, don't do it. There is not much we can add.

See these [Kalen Delaney](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/kalen_delaney/archive/2007/09/13/geek-city-the-resource-database.aspx) and [Unnamed](http://blogs.technet.com/b/beatrice/archive/2008/11/19/the-hidden-database-in-sql-server-2005-and-2008.aspx) (although I disagree with some of that)

As for what system objects..

- most "system tables" still work in SQL Server 2005 [says MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187997%28SQL.90%29.aspx)
- what was [discontinued](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262%28SQL.90%29.aspx)
- what [will be removed/are deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Very little of relevance. sys.segments goes back to SQL Server 6.5 for example.